# create custom authenticate controller with different database filed in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Auth::attempt(['u_email'=>$credentials['email'],'u_password'=>sha1($credentials['password'])])

i'm use this code for authentication but i'm getting `Undefined index: password` error can any one help for create custom authentication control without changing in vendor library

Thank you in advance for help me...

Comment: Before I start describing solution - why do you need to use u_email and u_password instead of just email and password? Are those the columns in your database?

Comment: yes, I need to change that because of I'm not having permission to change database field name it's affect to other...

Comment: and also I'm find one JWTAuthentication but it's give same error

Comment: What user provider are you using? Database or Eloquent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 things you need to do.

1. Pass plain-text password to **Auth::attempt()** as Laravel will hash that itself before verifying it against the hash stored in the database.

   ```
   Auth::attempt(['u_email'=>$credentials['email'],'password' => $credentials['password']]);
   ```
2. Pass password as **password**, not **u_password** to **Auth::attempt()**. The key doesn't need to match the password column name (why? see point 3.), but it must be equal to **password** - see point 1 for example.
3. Implement **getAuthPassword()** method in your user model, that will return value of **u_password** column. This method is used by user provider to fetch the password hash that is later verified against what was passed to **Auth::attempt()**

   ```
   //in your User.php
   public function getAuthPassword() {
     return $this->u_password;
   }
   ```

Comment: can you please provide me one example for that

Comment: thank you sir it's worked can you please tell me how you find ? it's for further reference only

Comment: Jost browse Laravel code to see how authentication works internally

Comment: thank you sir for help me
can I use sha1 instead of  laravel hash